# SELECT the requested cell by using MAX() and SUM() functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that returns the an account name of the **MAX** deposits sum. deposits can be added each day but the sum is per month.

2 tables:

**Accounts**(Id, Name)

**Deposits** (Id, Date, Deposit)

I need to get the name of Account with the largest deposit sum in a current month.

For example:

**Accounts**

1   Name1

2   Name2

3   Name3

4   Name4

**Deposits**

1   12  2010-01-01

1   13  2010-01-02

2   30  2010-02-02

3   15  2010-02-02

4   10  2010-02-03

1   30  2010-02-02

The result should be Name1.

Till now I create a query that return a table with the Sum for each month for each account:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT SUM(Deposits.deposit) as SumMonth , Deposits.account_id as Id
FROM Deposits
GROUP BY Deposits.account_id, MONTH(Deposits.Date) 
) 
as A INNER JOIN Accounts ON Accounts.id = A.Id
```

That's query returns:

25   1  1   Name1
30   1  1   Name1
30   2  2   Name2
15   3  3   Name3
10   4  4   Name4

Any Ideas ??

Comment: Your results have two rows with `SumMonth = 30 = max`. Why the result should be only `Name1` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Tx for your comment, you right, but there is no meaning for which name will shows in case of equal values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have the first step done yourself.
Now take this query, Order By SumMonth DESC. With TOP 1 you get the first.

Like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
(
SELECT SUM(Deposits.deposit) as SumMonth , Deposits.account_id as Id
FROM Deposits
GROUP BY Deposits.account_id, MONTH(Deposits.Date) 
) 
AS a INNER JOIN Accounts ON Accounts.id = a.Id
ORDER BY Accounts.SumMonth DESC
```